# GNU Parallel and the GPU?

Tags: gpu, gnu-parallel

I am interested in getting GNU Parallel to run some numerical computation tasks on the GPU.  Generically speaking, here is my initial approach:

1. Write the tasks to use OpenCL, or some other GPU interfacing library
2. Call GNU parallel on the task list (*I am unsure about the need for this step*)

This brought up the following questions:

1. Does my approach/use-case benefit from the use of GNU Parallel (i.e. should I even use it here)?
2. Does GNU Parallel offer a built-in mechanism for running tasks in
   parallel on a GPU?
3. If so, how can I configure GNU Parallel to do
   this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern CPUs have multiple cores, that means they can run different instructions at the same time; so when core 1 is running a MUL core 2 may be running an ADD. This is also called MIMD - Multiple Instructions, Multiple Data.

GPUs, however, cannot run different instructions at the same time. They excel in running the same instruction on a large amounts of data; SIMD - Single Instruction, Multiple Data.

Modern GPUs have multiple cores that are each SIMD.

So where does GNU Parallel fit into this mix?

GNU Parallel starts programs. If your program uses a GPU and you have one single GPU core on your system, GNU Parallel will not make much sense. But if you have, say, 4 GPU cores on your system, then it makes sense to keep these 4 cores running at the same time. So if your program reads the variable CUDA_​VISIBLE_​DEVICES to decide which GPU core to run on, you can do something like this:

```
seq 10000 | parallel -j4 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='$(({%} - 1))' compute {}
```

Comment: With this, I get: "/bin/bash: CUDA_​VISIBLE_​DEVICES=0: command not found" etc for every input.

Comment: @CarlLemaire You have an unprintable char in your string (\x200b). My guess is stackoverflow's editor has inserted that.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Comment: I am not sure how well this works - at least with pytorch.
When I try to use parallel + call multiple python scipts that do inference in the way described above (setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`), all the computation goes to the first GPU and it results in CUDA OOM errors.
basically the first GPU works fully (utilization+memory), while the rest have 3mb occupied and 0% utilization.

I know that pytorch internally has functionality for that (`DataParallel`/`DistributedDataParallel`), but parallel doesn't seem to play very nice with torch (or CUDA), at least for me

Comment: @tony.crete Does the program respect CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES? Otherwise it obviously will not work.